# Jquery issue with the loop

Tags: jquery

```
var length=$('div p').length;

for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {

if(i==5) {

  do something

}
}
```

Im triying to loop though a div and start from the first(0 index) element and when the loop reaches the 5th index i want it to do something. My question is, is the code right and if not where are my errors

Comment: The code does not check if the length could be less than 5.

Comment: Also, why do you think this loop is wrong? Are you facing a problem? Are you getting any errors? As it stands, this question is more of a code review question rather than a programming question.

Comment: Is it looping through `divs` or checking `p` in the divs?

Comment: how many `<p>` are there in the div/s?

Comment: I have a div that contains 5 'p' and when i click on a button i want those p to clone after the last one starting from the first one(one on each click). That is why i want the 5th index to be equal to the 0

Answer (score 1):

You can do simpler with jQuery :

```
$('div p').each(function(i) {
    if (i==5) { do something }
});
```

In the function, `this` is your current element. You can see (in the console) what it is using this code :

```
$('div p').each(function(i) {
    console.log(this); // prints the paragraph in the console
    if (i==5) { do something }
});
```

If you want to do something only with the 6th element (index starts at 0), no need to loop : simply do

```
var element = $('div p:eq(5)');
```

Answer (score 0):

On the fifth element, i==4 .. Because on the first element i==0. That is your error

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/67d8k/

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('div p:lt(5)').clone().appendTo('div');
});
```

Comment: checkout this code. if this is something you are looking for.